# Как из кода сделать цикл

Tags: python-3.x

Ребята помогите сделать цикл из моего кода. Не хватает мозгов)

Программа выдает буквы в перемешку из которых нужно собрать слово.

Собрать нужно таким образом - указать через пробел номер буквы, которую нужно переместить и номер буквы, на который нужно переместить
букву: 3 1 - третью букву поставить первой.

Как сделать, чтобы слово в переменной `anagrama` в конце моего кода была такой же как и в начале программы `print("Cоставьте слово из:",anagrama)`.

Надеюсь, что написал понятно.

```
words_for_anagram = ["крокодил", "гепард", "акула", "ягуар"]
word = random.choice(words_for_anagram)  # берем случайное слово из списка

for l in word:  # считываю слово по буквах
    anagram_word.append(l)  # записываю каждую букву в список anagram_word

random.shuffle(anagram_word)  # перемешиваю буквы - делаю анаграму
anagrama = "".join(anagram_word)  # склеиваем буквы
print("Cоставьте слово из:", anagrama)

user_input = input("Введите:").split(" ")
first_number = int(user_input[0])
second_number = int(user_input[1])

# запомиаем букву, которую хотим переставить
remembered_first_letter = anagrama[first_number]
print("первая буква", remembered_first_letter)

anagram_word.pop(first_number)  # удаляем букву из списка
print(" тут:", anagram_word)

anagram_word.insert(second_number, remembered_first_letter)  # вставляем сохраненную букву

anagrama = "".join(anagram_word)  # склеиваем буквы
print(" теперь: {} получилось слово: {}".format(anagram_word, anagrama))
```

Comment: Прикольно сделал.Попробуй перед for l in word поставить цикл while true
это бесконечный цикл ,как ты уже догадался).100 гарантии не даю.

Comment: Вместо цикла можно просто: `anagram_word = list(word)`. Пользуйтесь форматированием кода, а то больно смотреть (а код чаще смотрят чем пишут)

Answer (score 0):

Перед последним блоком поставьте условие `while anagramma != word`

Цикл будет крутиться пока слово не будет угадано.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, цикл, все получилось, прога будет работать пока юзер не угадает слово из анаграммы.

```
import random
anagram_word = []
remembered_number=0
new_anagram_world = []

words_for_anagram = ["крокодил","гепард","акула","ягуар"]
word = random.choice(words_for_anagram)#берем случайое слово из списка

for l in word:#считываю слово по буквах
 anagram_word.append(l)#записываю каждую букву в список anagram_word

random.shuffle(anagram_word)#перемешиваю буквы - делаю анаграму
anagrama = "".join(anagram_word)# склеиваем буквы

new_anagrama = ""

while not new_anagrama==word:# работает пока слово не будет = слову из списка

 print("Cоставьте слово из:",anagrama)
 user_input = input("Введите:").split(" ")
 first_number = int(user_input[0])# первая буква
 second_number = int(user_input[1])# вторая буква

 remembered_first_letter = anagrama[first_number]#запомиаем букву, которую хотим переставить
 print("первая буква",remembered_first_letter)
 anagram_word.pop(first_number)# удаляем букву из списка
 print("Что лежит тут:",anagram_word)
 anagram_word.insert(second_number,remembered_first_letter)# вставляем сохраненную букву
 anagrama = "".join(anagram_word)  # склеиваем буквы
 new_anagrama = anagrama
 print("получилось слово:",new_anagrama)

 if new_anagrama == word:
  print("получилось слово:", new_anagrama,"и это правильно! Вы молодец!")
```